# need to get two aggregate values from two different table and should group the values by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having two different tables with no connection between them but, need to get count of created date for a duration of last 12 months and from other table need to get sum of values which are  present in last 12 months. i am not able to group them according their month wise

```
select 
  (select sum(addrequest) as sumadd
 from fileimport as fi
  WHERE   fi.StartImportTime > DATEADD(m, -12, current_timestamp)) as addcount,
       (select Count(e.created)as countcreated FROM employee as e 
        inner join client as c
  on e.ClientID = c.ClientID
   WHERE   e.created > DATEADD(m, -12, current_timestamp)) as createdcount
```

By this query i am able to get only values in below format

```
AddCount  CreatedCount

* 806           203
```

but i am looking for something in this manner

```
Date         Addcount  CreatedCount

* Apr 2014      25         20

*  Mar 2014     50         24

  Feb 2014      60         24

   : 

 * May 2013     82         76
```

if i try to add additional date column in select its giving out error.
how can i get the desired result

the table structure of two table are

```
FileImport table
FileID   Name          StartImportTime            AddRequest  updateRequest 
 1       examplename   2014-02-25 16:55:57.290     25          12

Employee table
employeeid   Name          CreatedDate               LastUpdate                
12          examplename     2014-02-27 14:39:42.750   2014-02-27 14:39:42.750
```

I will displaying the data in ssrs report

Comment: Can you please post your table structure? The query is rather confusing

Comment: @TomasPastircak sorry for confusion, i hope now you have a better picture

Comment: You need to join the tables. Right now you are bringing back two unrelated aggregate columns. As Tomas said, please post your table structures.

Comment: @FumblesWithCode IT is for ssrs reporting would display data in ssrs reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is with `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(fi.thedate, ec.thedate) as thedate, fi.addcount, ec.createdcount
from (select cast(fi.StartImportTime as date) as thedate, sum(addrequest) as addcount
      from fileimport fi
      WHERE  > DATEADD(m, -12, current_timestamp)
     ) fi full outer join
     (select cast(e.created as date) as thedateCount(e.created) as createdcount
      FROM employee e inner join
           client c
           on e.ClientID = c.ClientID
      WHERE e.created > DATEADD(m, -12, current_timestamp)
     ) ec
     on fi.thedate = ec.thedate;
```

The `full outer join` ensures that you will get all dates that have data, even those that do not have both.

Comment: To clarify why I avoided solution like this: Although `FULL OUTER JOIN` would do the trick, it is better to avoid it, as it often confuses the query optimizer and can't correctly use indexes. It is better to join on something that is already known and find matching entries on it. Some more details on this topic are available [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/19/Full-Outer-Joins.aspx)

Comment: @TomasPastircak . . . I'm trying to phrase this as gracefully as possible, because a "religious" argument about full outer joins isn't worth the effort.  Performance may be an issue; I note that the tests in blog are 7 years old and hence refer to much earlier versions of SQL Server.  In addition, the comments on the blog do a good job of explaining different points of view regarding `full outer join`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you need to do. I have rewritten your query using CTE to make it more readable.

```
;WITH employeesWithDates AS(
    SELECT e.created,
    FROM employee e 
    INNER JOIN client as c
        on e.ClientID = c.ClientID
    WHERE e.created > DATEADD(m, -12, current_timestamp)
), FilesWithDates AS(
   SELECT fi.StartImportTime 
   FROM fileimport fi
   WHERE fi.StartImportTime > DATEADD(m, -12, current_timestamp))
), AvailableDates AS (
   SELECT created AS date FROM employeesWithDates UNION ALL SELECT StartImportTime As Date From FilesWithDates
)
SELECT convert(varchar(2),DATEPART(m,d.date)) + ' ' + convert(varchar(4),DATEPART(y,d.date)),
COUNT(f.StartImportTime) AddCount,
COUNT(e.created) CreatedCount
FROM AvailableDates d
LEFT JOIN employeesWithDates e ON DATEPART(m,d.date) = DATEPART(m,e.created) AND DATEPART(y,d.date) = DATEPART(y,e.created) 
LEFT JOIN FilesWithDates f ON DATEPART(m,d.date) = DATEPART(m,f.StartImportTime) AND DATEPART(y,d.date) = DATEPART(y,f.created) 
GROUP BY convert(varchar(2),DATEPART(m,d.date)) + ' ' + convert(varchar(4),DATEPART(y,d.date))
```

Comment: thanks fpr the response, getting two errors while executing the script

Comment: in last line at DATEAPART "Incorrect syntax near 'DATEPART'."

Comment: ya thanks, i fixed it now getting another error invalid object name 'dates' in first line

Comment: sorry to disturb you do you mean replace employeewithdates to avaliabledates,  if i did its saying duplicate common table expression name 'AvailableDates' was specified

Comment: No, I have improved the query, should be OK now

Comment: working correctly thanks for your help, highly appreciate you for your time spent.:)